# Convert a list of stringified lists into a dataframe whilst maintaining index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame coming from an API source, I'm trying to wrangle the data whilst not massively changing my original dataframe (don't want to do a cartesian product essentially)

```
data = ["[['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','4'],['foo2','bar2','55.21']]",
        "[['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','5']]",
        "[['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','6'],['foo1','bar1',''],['foo2','bar2','57.75']]"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [0,1,2],'arr' : data})
```

---

```
print(df)
      id                                                arr
0   0  [['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','4'],['...
1   1       [['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','5']]
2   2  [['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','6'],['...
```

The `Key` `Value` `Metric` tells the order of the arrays within what I'm trying to do is order it in a dictionary fashion of {key : value} where the key is the `Key` & `Metric` fields joined and the value is `-1` index of the nested list.

The source data is coming via excel & the MS Graph API, I don't envisage that it will change, but it may so I'm trying to come up with a dynamic solution.

my target dataframe is :

```
target_df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [0,1,2],
                         'foo_bar' : [4,5,6],
                         'foo1_bar1' : [np.nan, np.nan,''],
                         'foo2_bar2' : [55.21, np.nan, 57.75]})
```

---

```
print(target_df)

   id  foo_bar  foo1_bar1  foo2_bar2
0   0        4        NaN      55.21
1   1        5        NaN        NaN
2   2        6                 57.75
```

my own attemps have been to use literal_eval from the `ast` library to get the first list which will always be the `Key` `Metric` & `Value` column - there maybe in future a `Key` `Metric` , `Metric2`, `Value` field - hence my desire to keep things dynamic.

there will always be a single `Key` & `Value` field.

### Own attempt :

```
from ast import literal_eval

literal_eval(df['arr'][0])[0]
#['Key', 'Value', 'Metric']
```

with this i replaced the list characters and split by `,` then converted the result to a dataframe :

```
df['arr'].str.replace('\[|\]','').str.split(',',expand=True)
```

however after this I haven't made much clear head-way and wondering If im going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Is there any reason why the Key, Value and Metric strings are "out of order" compared to the actual sublists? (I hope that was clear enough)

Comment: @AMC - sorry typo took a while to formulate the question went through several iterations.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not sure I understand the question completely. What does the index have to do with this?

Comment: @AMC the index is the original data frame, I basically want to explode these lists into new columns on my original dataframe before ingesting the data into my datawarehouse - in short, i want to keep the original shape.

Comment: Alright, there are a few different questions then. If you get those lists as a DataFrame, do you know where to go from there?

Comment: For the benefit of any future readers can you clarify once and for all the format of the data, and simplify the whole index part? Why do you mention the cartesian product, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df2=df["arr"].map(eval).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({f"{el[0]}_{el[1]}": el[2] for el in x[1:]}))

df2["id"]=df["id"]
```

Output:

```py
  foo_bar foo2_bar2 foo1_bar1  id
0       4     55.21       NaN   0
1       5       NaN       NaN   1
2       6     57.75             2
```

Comment: Thanks for this - very nice use of f-strings, i turned it into a function to add some more logic but it's v.good. thanks my man.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand every aspect of the question, but here's what I have so far.

```py
import ast

import pandas as pd

data = ["[['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','4'],['foo2','bar2','55.21']]",
        "[['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','5']]",
        "[['Key','Metric','Value'],['foo','bar','6'],['foo1','bar1',''],['foo2','bar2','57.75']]"]

nested_lists = [ast.literal_eval(elem)[1:] for elem in data]

row_dicts = [{'_'.join([key, metric]): value for key, metric, value in curr_list} for curr_list in nested_lists]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=row_dicts)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  foo_bar foo2_bar2 foo1_bar1
0       4     55.21       NaN
1       5       NaN       NaN
2       6     57.75
```

`nested_lists` and `row_dicts` are list comprehension since it makes debugging easier, but you can of course transform them into generator expressions.

Comment: this looks promising will test now.

Comment: this was also good, but my actual data doesn't come from lists it's from an API

Comment: @Datanovice Unfortunately, your post, and a comment you made, indicated the exact opposite. In what format do you get the data? From the accepted answer it looks like you just wanted to add an existing column to the new data? Speaking of accepted answer, it uses `eval()` which is extremely unsafe.

Comment: by lists I mean the variable `data` it comes in from an API call in the format of the first dataframe in the column `arr` thanks tho!

Comment: @Datanovice I’m guessing the “API call” is a method which calls an API and converts the result to a DataFrame? Or are you creating the DataFrame?

Comment: It's a little more complex, it's part of an ETL pipeline think of Excel + Custom Web App > AWS Blob Store > Airflow > JSON File > Pyspark + some minor pandas.

Comment: @Datanovice Right, but which parts of that process do you actually have control over? At the point where you first get the data, what format is it in?

Comment: I control everything bar the excel + Web app I get the format like the first data frame above its the output from the web app, painful I know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206177/discussion-between-amc-and-datanovice).

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can loop over each row and use `literal_eval`, create dataframes, `set_index` the first two columns and `transpose`. then `concat` plus rename the columns, and create the column id:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df_target = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_records(literal_eval(x)).drop(0).set_index([0,1]).T 
                       for x in df.arr.to_numpy()], 
                       ignore_index=True, 
                       keys=df.id) #to keep the ids
# rename the columns as wanted
df_target.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(*col) for col in df_target.columns]
# add the ids as a column
df_target = df_target.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'id'})

print (df_target)
   id foo_bar foo1_bar1 foo2_bar2
0   0       4       NaN     55.21
1   1       5       NaN       NaN
2   2       6               57.75
```

Comment: firing up cluster to test = )

Comment: Ben this was really good - i tried to make it work for my target dataset which had many more levels of nested lists but it kept coming out wrong - it pushed me in the right direction though, thank you so much for your help and apologies for not conveying my problem correctly.

Comment: @Datanovice glad you found the way to go for your pb :)

Comment: @Datanovice _my target dataset which had many more levels of nested lists_ ......